# Why foreach loop fails at last row of gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have put a code to COLOR the background of GRIDVIEW Cell# 14 if cell's text != "nbsp;" and it does work except for the last row. It doesn't color the last row even it isn't equal to "nbsp;"

```
protected void grdviewCases_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdviewCases.Rows)
            {
                if (gr.Cells[14].Text != "&nbsp;")
                {
                    gr.Cells[14].BackColor = Color.Red; ;
                    gr.Cells[14].ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be the case that the new row gets added to the Rows collection only after the RowDataBound event occurs. I would check that first.

Comment: Also, why iterate through the entire rows collection after each row is databound and not work on the newly bound row only?

Comment: A simple solution would be to eliminate the foreach instruction and in the remaining code replace gr with e.Row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need not loop rows in RowDataBound event, you may just use `e` object to reference each row

```
protected void grdviewCases_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[14].Text != "&nbsp;")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[14].BackColor = Color.Red; ;
                e.Row.Cells[14].ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            }
        }
    }
```

For more details check [system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)